# Is it possible to join multiple text characters into one curved path in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, path

Other than creating an entirely new curved path and entering text, is there a way to combine separate text characters into one path? I know it is possible to outline them first but ideally they would need to be retained as text.

[image]

Comment: Copy the text in path 2 join the paths, inser tab, paste text, adjust tab. Not sure theres any benefit in this case.

Comment: "Other than creating an entirely new curved path and entering text" -- not really... you wouldn't need to *type* the text, you can merely copy and paste it, but you'd need a new path.

Comment: @joojaa sorry I didn't get. I tried joining paths but since it contains text it doesn't join. i think that's the problem OP is facing.

Comment: @Funzo you want join Eldon and River so it becomes in same direction like a single phrase? (like Eldon Peak)

Comment: @Vikas.. copy the separate text objects... start a *new* Point Text.. paste.. it'll be one word.

Comment: @Vikas that's right. It's cause it's text. But they need to stay in roughly the same positions and become curved text, as the pic on right. In this case the two words are spread out a bit, so just combining the letters in each word as a path would do.

Comment: @Scott thanks. Was trying to see if there is a way to avoid creating a new path each time then pasting/typing the text.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, @Funzo there isn't.

Comment: @Funzo you can use the white arrow to select only the path to copy it as just a path. Also if you overset you whould be able to link the paths together with the red plus sign.